# PHP OpenID Connect Provider implementations

Tags: php, open-source, openid, openid-connect

I am going to build this standardized protocol, OpenID Connect:

- http://openid.net/connect/
- http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html

But just wonder, do you guys know, is there any existing both OpenSource and commercial PHP products? The list known products that I have known:

- https://bitbucket.org/PEOFIAMP/phpoidc
- http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/

Just for clarification:

- I am not looking OpenID Connect Client.
- I am not looking existing OpenID Connect Provider like Google OAuth2 does.
- I am looking my own OpenID Connect Provider.

Any help and information will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: WIP: https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/oauth2-server-library

Comment: hmm. I also found only those 2 libs. Both seem to be rather dead in term of development and support.

Comment: With bshaeffer one seems like password grant doesn't work according to spec, at least I couldn't get it to return id_token properly. Found this one as well:  
https://packagist.org/packages/steverhoades/oauth2-openid-connect-client

Comment: Have you found the solution? If yes, then please share. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

There's [phpOIDC](https://bitbucket.org/PEOFIAMP/phpoidc) as well. In general the OpenID Foundation tries to maintain an up-to-date list of protocol implementations (both client and server) [here](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, I knew that library already. I was wondering something else from my list above. Thanks.